# How to switch to a particular navigation panel with the click of a button in a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

### Goal

Click on a button to switch to a particular tab in shiny.

### Working example

This works:

```
library(bslib)
library(shiny)

ui <- bslib::page_navbar(
  title = "App Title",
  id = "titlePage",
  
  navset_tab(
    id = "tabs",
    nav_panel(
      "one",
      textInput(
        'tabOneText',
        label = "You're on tab 1"
      ),
      actionButton(
        inputId = "ac",
        "Select your tab"
      ),
      verbatimTextOutput("boo")
    ),
    nav_panel(
      "two",
      textInput(
        "tabTwoText",
        label = "You're on tab 2"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$ac,{

    if (input$ac>0){
    nav_select(
      "tabs",
      selected = "two"
    )
    }
  })
  
  output$boo <- renderPrint({
    input$ac
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### Not working with module

When I use a module the panel switch does not work:

```
library(bslib)
library(shiny)



my_module_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(
      inputId = ns("ac"),
      "Select your tab"
    ),
    verbatimTextOutput(ns("boo"))
  )
}



my_module_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$ac,{
      
      if (input$ac>0){
        nav_select(
          "tabs",
          selected = "two"
        )
      }
    })
    
    output$boo <- renderPrint({
      input$ac
    })
  }
  )
  
}



ui <- bslib::page_navbar(
  title = "App Title",
  id = "titlePage",
  
  navset_tab(
    id = "tabs",
    nav_panel(
      "one",
      textInput(
        'tabOneText',
        label = "You're on tab 1"
      ),
      my_module_ui("btn")
    ),
    nav_panel(
      "two",
      textInput(
        "tabTwoText",
        label = "You're on tab 2"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  my_module_server("btn")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How to tell the module to switch to the selected tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forewarning - I'm just reading up on modules so I don't fully understand them at this moment. However, I've done a little digging and think I know what the issue is.

In `my_module_server` you are interacting with a couple of inputs, `input$ac` and `input$tabs`. In `my_module_ui`, you have correctly added the namespaces for the `input$ac` and `output$boo` but there's no way to add the namespace for `input$tabs`.

Therefore, when running `my_module_server(...)`, the moduleServer function recognizes `input$ac` and `ouptut$boo` and updates accordingly but it doesn't "see" `input$tabs`. Since I believe it's technically expecting `` input$`btn-tabs` `` . Where "btn" is the id you're using.

My current recommendation would be to either reconfigure `my_module_ui`, such that you include `navset_tab` and add a namespace for it.

Or a quick fix would be to hard code the namespace within your current ui.

```
navset_tab(
  id = NS("btn","tabs"), # hard coded to "btn"
  ...
)
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. I did understand the issue you comprehensively described but wasn't sure if specifying `NS` in the main UI was appropriate. One problem though: If a module is used multiple times with different IDs, then the hard-coded solution does not work.

Comment: In that situation, it may be best to implement nested modules. One for the navset_tab ui (parent) and your module. Then you can pass your current module into the parent.